# Number of sessions by age group in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I am pivoting my GA data to view number of sessions by Device Category for each age group of my users. Here is a snapshot of my data:

[image]

Removing the age breakdown for this data, I can see there are actually 606,737 sessions from mobile device. But after age breakdown, I can see only 196,027.

I am aware that google doesn't track users who are below 18 yrs of age. Is the difference only because of this?

Answer (score 0):

Demographic data is only available for subset of users and doesn't represent your overall traffic. Google Can not gather demographic information for users whose Device ID is unknown or they have no activity profile. You may find more information [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en)